# django Same Host multi app Nginx Gunicorn

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

Run multiple django applications on one server

`environment`
`python3`
`nginx`
`django2`

I cannot dual django run. always `Bad Request (400)`

django app1 settings

nginx settings
`/etc/nginx/conf.d/abc.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name .abc.co;
    rewrite ^ https: // $ server_name $ request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name .abc.co;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.co/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.co/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:! ADH:! MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  location / static {
        alias /home/abc.co/static;
    }

    location / media {
        alias /home/abc.co/media;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $ proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $ http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $ scheme;
    }
}
```

gunicorn settings
/etc/systemd/system/abc.service

```
[Unit]
Description = gunicorn
After = network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory = / home / abc.co
ExecStart = / usr / bin / gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 config.wsgi: application

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

django settings
/home/123.co/config/settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['abc.co']
```

Check the access to the main domain with the above settings, and confirm that the code is working properly.

Next, trying to build another django app on the same server and IP address. Then its failed.

django app2 Setting ↓

nginx settings
`/etc/nginx/conf.d/123.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name .123.jp;
    rewrite ^ https: // $ server_name $ request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name. 123.jp;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/123.jp/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/123.jp/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:! ADH:! MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  location / static {
        alias /home/123.jp/static;
    }

    location / media {
        alias /home/123.jp/media;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $ proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $ http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $ scheme;
    }
}
```

gunicorn settings
`/etc/systemd/system/123.service`

```
[Unit]
Description = gunicorn
After = network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory = / home / 123.jp
ExecStart = / usr / bin / gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8080 config.wsgi: application

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

django settings
`/home/123.jp/config/settings.py`

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['123.jp']
```

The first domain is operating normally, but every time you access the second domain
`Bad Request (400)`
It will come out.
`Bad Request (400) is due to access from a server that is not specified in ALLOWED_HOSTS`

What I tried:

1. gunicorn configuration and nginx configuration
   127.0.0.1:8080 to
   127.0.0.2:8000 Change to. test
2. - `reboot`
   - `systemctl restart nginx`
   - `systemctl daemon-reload`
   - Restart by any method
3. - `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` #Setting to accept all with wildcards
   - `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['abc.co', '123.34.1.123']` #Setting to accept domain and server IP

Even if I do everything, it does not work, and even though I have specified the domain properly in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, if I start two django, 'abc.co' is not in `ALLOWED_HOSTS` on the django debug screen Can not be displayed. And vomiting errors.

--Postscript--

Hi, thank you for answering.
I did

django app2 Setting ↓

nginx settings /etc/nginx/conf.d/123.conf

```
server_2 {
    listen 80;
    server_name .123.jp;
    rewrite ^ https: // $ server_name $ request_uri? permanent;
}

server_2 {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name. 123.jp;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/123.jp/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/123.jp/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:! ADH:! MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  location / static {
        alias /home/123.jp/static;
    }

    location / media {
        alias /home/123.jp/media;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $ proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $ http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $ scheme;
    }
}
```

then

```
nginx -t
```

```
[emerg] 806#806: unknown directive "server_2" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/123.jp.conf:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: for starters your nginx configs will conflict. Let me post how I host more than one application using nginx on one server

Comment: first can you change the nginx conf in the second app to `server_2 {
    listen 80;
    server_name .123.jp;
    rewrite ^ https: // $ server_name $ request_uri? permanent;
}` instead of just `server` because that will cause conflicts

Comment: did it work? let us know how it went

Comment: no this is not working...